# How to assign numerical value to a selection in a form Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement

I'm attempting to build a form that will allow someone to order a pizza and display the invoice as the user builds their pizza.

I've managed to get the options the user selects to show up, but I'm lost as to how to assign a price to the options. Ideally, I'd love to assign a price to the sizes and eventually a price after three toppings are selected (and premium toppings). 
I also run into an issue where the invoice will only fill out if the function sizeOfPizza is the only function. Adding other Javascript will negate this.

```js
//display choice of size of pizza
function sizeOfPizza(size) {
  document.getElementById("pizzaSize").value = size;
}

//display choice of size price 
function determineSizePrice(size) {
  document.getElementById("pizzaSizePrice").value = ???? <somehow this would result in the correct if statement becoming the price of the selection> 

  if (option.value == "personal") {
    var pizzaSizePrice = 5

  } else if (option.value == "Medium") {
    var pizzaSizePrice = 8

  } else if (option.value == "Large") {
    var pizzaSizePrice = 10

  } else if (option.value == "Extra Large") {
    var pizzaSizePrice = 12

  } else if (option.value == "Holy Pizza") {
    var pizzaSizePrice = 20

  }

}
```

```html
<h3> Select Size </h3>

<form id="pizza-size">
  <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="sizeOfPizza(this.value)"  value="Personal"> Personal (4 Slices) <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="sizeOfPizza(this.value)"  value="Medium"> Medium (8 slices)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="sizeOfPizza(this.value)"  value="Large"> Large (10 slices) <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="sizeOfPizza(this.value)"  value="Extra Large"> Extra Large (12 slices)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="sizeOfPizza(this.value)"  value="Holy Pizza"> Holy Pizza Batman (24 slices) <br>
</form>
<br>


<br> Pizza Size: <output id="pizzaSize"> </output> <br> Pizza Size Price: <output id="pizzaSizePrice">
    
    <br>
```

Comment: You cant have the same element attribute twice (`onclick`). Also `= var sizePrice` is a syntax error.

Comment: I made you a snippet and formatted the code. Fix the console error. `document.getElementById("pizzaSizePrice").value =
    var sizePrice` is not valid JS. Also have ONE onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some better practices

Note your script had spelling mistakes in Personal (lowercase), a missing `</output>` and other issues

```js
const prices = {
  "Personal": 5,
  "Medium": 8,
  "Large": 10,
  "Extra Large": 12,
  "Holy Pizza": 20
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads
  document.getElementById("pizza-size").addEventListener("click", function(e) { // pass the event  - in this case the click event
    var tgt = e.target; // what was clicked
    if (tgt.name === "size") { // is it one of the radios?
      var val = tgt.value; // save the value once (DRY principle)
      document.getElementById("pizzaSize").value = val;
      document.getElementById("pizzaSizePrice").value = prices[val]; // look up the price in the prices object
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<h3> Select Size </h3>
<form id="pizza-size">
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Personal"> Personal (4 Slices) <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Medium"> Medium (8 slices)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large"> Large (10 slices) <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Large"> Extra Large (12 slices)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="Holy Pizza"> Holy Pizza Batman (24 slices) <br>
</form><hr/>
Pizza Size: <output id="pizzaSize"> </output> <br> 
Pizza Size Price: <output id="pizzaSizePrice"></output>
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't learned const (or let) yet, I'll be experimenting with this to better understand it!

Comment: Then use var. const is just to show it is not changing during the script execution.

Comment: I added more comments for you